# Объявление массивов в С++

Tags: c++

Инициализация массива в Java:

```
int[] array = new int[10];
```

В то время как в С++:

```
int array[10];
```

Вопрос. Есть какая-то разница в том, что в С++ не используется оператор `new` и когда используется new, а когда нет?

С джавы я уже привык, что запись: `int array[]` - это только создания ссылки.

Comment: Вообще-то к "инициализации" это не имеет никакого отношения. Речь идет об *объявлении* массива.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Аналогом джавового выражения в C++ будет `int *arr = new int[10];`, ибо иначе массив выделяется на стеке, а не в хипе.

Семантики выражения `int array[10];` в Java нет.

Comment: можно узнать, почему в джаве сочли это лишним и не добавили? 
ведь если я не ошибаюсь, инициализация типа 'int arr[]` называется статическое, но если передавать ее как параметр функции, работает как передача по ссылке, а не по значению, что достаточно сильно путает разработчика. есть какие-то плюсы от этого, кроме как работы с памятью?

Comment: @DimaKhodan массив чего-либо в С/C++ - это просто указатель на последоватьльность объекторв конкретного типа. Тобишь что `int arr[10]`, что `int * arr = new int [10];` - оба указатели, просто в первом случае память выделяется в стэке, а во втором случае - в куче. Массив не может передаваться "по значению" - может передаваться только как указатель.

Comment: @DimaKhodan, почему не добавили -вопрос хороший. Возможно потому, что это усложнило бы язык, да еще и давало бы соблазнительную возможность передавать такие массивы-значения в методы, что пагубно повлияло бы на производительность (ибо значимые типы копируются при передаче). Представьте: под каждый используемый тип массива (вариации как типов элементов, так и размеров) требуется своя функция. В C++ это решается [с помощью шаблонов](https://ideone.com/L91P3O), а в С - передачей только указателя на элемент и сдвиганием на соседние с помощью адресной арифметики. Оба подхода в Java недопустимы

Comment: @DimaKhodan, В C/C++ действительно есть тип *статического* массива (который неявно может приводиться к указателю на первый его элемент, но все же это разные понятия), но передавать его непосредственно в функции нельзя - только в виде ссылки (можно сгенерировать с помощью шаблонов, будет что-то вроде `int(&)[10]` ) или указателя - несчастное наследие cи. В стандартной библиотеке есть [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), который декорирует сырые статические массивы.

Comment: @free_ze я посидел поигрался с этими массивами и указателями на первый элемент и вроде как понял, в чем дело и что вообще происходит. спасибо.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch `int arr[10]` - это не указатель.

Comment: @VTT да, я там не совсем верно выразился: я имел ввиду, что такая запись означает создание указателя. Тобишь arr - это указатель.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Нет, `arr` - это не указатель и никаких указателей при записи `int arr[10]` не создается. `arr` может явно и неявно приводиться к указателю, но указателем не является.

Comment: @VTT хм, возможно - точно не знаю, так что настаивать не буду

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, по этому поводу рекомендую ознакомиться с "Эффективным и современным С++" Мейерса, в первой главе эта тема поднимается в контексте вывода типов в шаблонах.

Answer (score 3):

В C++ более-менее value semantics, в частности, для обычного типа объявление локальной переменной автоматически означает создание на стеке локального объекта, который эта переменная и представляет. `new` — операция создания объекта где-то в памяти, его время жизни при этом в простейем случае никак не зависит от local scope; чтобы можно было написать `var = new Class;`, переменная `var` должна (без дополнительных телодвижений) иметь тип "указатель, совместимый с `Class *`".